# how to create and use an object from an other class in Java

Tags: java, class, object

I dont know how to create and use an object from an other class in an other class. for example, i want the Publisher to be created from another class (Item)

```
public class Item {
    private String title;
    private String publisher;
    private int price,year,quantity;

    Item(String title,String publisher,int price,int year,int quantity){
        //Constructor goes here 
    }
}

//this is the publisher class:

public class Publisher {

    private String name,address,country,city;

    Publisher(String name,String address,String country,String city){
        this.setName(name);
        this.setAddress(address);
        this.setCountry(country);
        this.setCity(city);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What did you try? It's very simple:

```
public class Item {
    ....
    void Test() {
        Publsiher p = new Publisher("a","b","c","d");
        //do some things
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Item{
    public Item(){
        Publisher p = new Publisher('Name','Address','Country','City');
    }
}
```

Inside the constructor Item() create a new Publisher object "p" with input values of your choice ('name','address, 'country', 'city').